# Loopback neq: null

Tags: javascript, postgresql, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying a query on a postgres database through the loopback api explorer:

```
{"where": {"archived_at":{ "neq": null }}}
```

However, I only get results where archived_at is null?

Comment: I'm not sure if checking for NULLs is implemented, there has been some discussion about this (isSet operator). If internally this is translated into `archived_at = NULL` then it won't work, since NULL is not equal to even NULL.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but it might help.  I'm using mongodb, and I get the same results from the query in your question, i.e. it contains records where the field is `null` but not records where the field is non-`null` (which is the opposite of what the query looks like it should give).  I also get the same if I use `{"where":{"archived_at":{}}}`.  But `{"where":{"archived_at":{"neq":{}}}}` gives me everything, unfiltered.  I'd love to know the answer to this, surely getting all records with a non-`null` value in a given field is a common use case.

Answer (score 16):

The following query worked for me...

```
{ "include": [ "currency" ], "where": { "currencyCode": { "neq":  null } } }
```

I was requesting tables that had a currencyCode...

(Sorry for the poor quality of my response, I just wanted to share, even I didn't have a straight answer to the OG's question, and I don't have enough props to comment)

Comment: I have same issue. i am missing ("") in neq. As in documentation they do not use ("") for other operators.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database. Based on postgresql in loopback 3.

For search integer / number null or not null value.

I think it depends on the database and loopback version.

1. You can try `like nlike` query in loopback (but how to use it depends on the db) https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html#ilike-and-nilike
2. Querying not null value

   Explorer:

   ```
   {"where": {"principalId": { "neq": "" }} }
   ```

   or in server

   ```
   {where: {"principalId": { neq: "" }} }
   ```
3. Try to direct query in database. Loopback allowed for that.

   ```
   "angular": "^1.6.3",
   "angular-messages": "^1.6.3",
   "angular-ui-validate": "^1.2.2",
   "async": "^2.1.5",
   "bower": "^1.8.0",
   "compression": "^1.6.2",
   "cors": "^2.8.1",
   "helmet": "^3.5.0",
   ```

> "loopback": "^3.7.0",

```
"loopback-boot": "^2.23.0",
"loopback-component-explorer": "^4.2.0",
"
```

> loopback-component-storage": "^3.2.0",

```
"loopback-connector-mongodb": "^3.0.1",
"loopback-connector-mysql": "^3.0.0",
"loopback-connector-postgresql": "^2.8.0",
"loopback-console": "^1.1.0",
"loopback-datasource-juggler": "^3.5.0",
"loopback-sdk-angular-cli": "^3.0.0",
"milligram": "^1.3.0",
"serve-favicon": "^2.4.2",
"strong-error-handler": "^2.0.0"
```